# mysql process list: "Creating sort index" or "sending data" very slow on indexed query

Tags: mysql

I'm on mysql 5.6, innoDB, here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activities use index (user_id_start_time_end_time) 
WHERE user_id=219439 
  AND end_time <= 1414524849 
  AND start_time >= 1413867600 
ORDER BY end_time DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

This started happening after an upgrade from 5.5, and it takes about 5-10 seconds to complete. th`user_id_start_time_end_time` is a compound index on user_id, start_time and end_time.

If if explain the query, I get :

`Using index condition; Using filesort` in the extra column and a reasonable amount of rows (~500).

If I take out the `ORDER BY end_time DESC LIMIT 1000` it's actually worse, the query gets stuck in `sending data` state, and completes in >10 seconds.

The table has about 150M rows.

EDIT1:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `start_time` (`start_time`),
  KEY `end_time` (`end_time`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id_start_time_end_time` (`user_id`,`start_time`,`end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=193763922 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

(slightly edited).

7.5 GB ram (on AWS RDS).

```
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 5839126528; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 374910
Buffer pool size   348224
Free buffers       7784
Database pages     318670
Old database pages 117550
Modified db pages  51295
Pending reads 18
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 8233948, not young 97502110
267.01 youngs/s, 1694.11 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11060592, created 116307, written 5005689
285.42 reads/s, 2.67 creates/s, 63.31 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 992 / 1000, young-making rate 7 / 1000 not 51 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 318670, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[144032]:cur[750], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

Comment: Could you post a create table statement? How big is your innodb buffer pool size on how much RAM? And also pretty reasonable that you query stuck on "sending data" if you remove the LIMIT and return all 150M row. Could you try again without ORDER BY but with the LIMIT?

Comment: edited the question. It seems slightly worse with the LIMIT but not ORDER BY.

Comment: have you tried running your query without the `use index`?

Comment: yes. same result. the explain statement returns the same number of rows, only more "possible keys"

Comment: I had once similar behavior as soon tables hit a certain size. In my case the index didn't fit in to the memory. Try to increase your innodb buffer pool size to 2/3 of your Ram. If you have 7.5 GB,  than increase it to 5 Gb

Comment: I think you're right - the memory wasn't enough. The innodb buffer was already at 3/4, so I simply upgraded the whole thing, seems to be fine now. I think it was trying to create the temp table on disk instead of in memory, and that's why it was taking so long.